# Delete all documents that don't match a term?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

How would I match all documents that don't match a term in lucene or lucene.net ?

If I want to delete all the documents that match a term it's easy :

```
writer.DeleteDocuments(new Term("SomeParameter", SomeValue));
```

But i actually need to do the opposite (I'm marking each updated document with a unique tag, I want to delete everything that wasn't updated, so everything whose tag is diferent from my tag, but it could be very diferent things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a query that matches all documents that don't have the term, but `BooleanQuery` cannot contain just a single `MUST_NOT` clause.

But you can use the following trick to bypass this:

```csharp
var query = new BooleanQuery();
query.Add(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), Occur.SHOULD);
query.Add(new Term("SomeParameter", someValue), Occur.MUST_NOT);
writer.DeleteDocuments(query);
```

Comment: Was hoping there was a solution to stick to the term parameter and not use queries but i went for something similar to this in the end, thanks!